# vb.net option strict disallows late binding when trying to add to array cant turn off

Tags: arrays, vb.net, option-strict

I am trying to build my combobox with items from my array, but am getting this error:

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub frmInventory_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim InvArray As Array
    InvArray = Inventory.BuildInvArray()
    Option Strict Off
    For i As Integer = 0 To 5
        cmbSystem.Items.Add(InvArray(i,1))
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: that is not valid code.  Option Strict is a directive that goes at the top of the module. you cant turn it off in the middle of an event or method

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using `Array.GetValue`

```
Private Sub frmInventory_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim InvArray As Array
    InvArray = Inventory.BuildInvArray()
    For i As Integer = 0 To 5
        cmbSystem.Items.Add(InvArray.GetValue(i, 1))
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks like a failed edit of your original question.  Just delete this as it will just confuse others.